# What are the size/second convertion rate that I can expect on compressed video

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ffmpeg

I am developing an app and I am quite hesitant on allowing my users to share videos.

Mainly due the space that videos can take up in the server which adds a huge maintainance  cost.

I have been reading around and I can see that there are lots of different libraries that allow me to compress video on iOS to make it easy to share.

After much researching I couldn't find any estimate on  file size / second after compressed.)

I was wondering if anyone could share their experience  with what file size / second I could expect with your preferred library in a video quality setting that is reasonable for mobile  (I guess medium).

Comment: It's complicated and depends on the input video complexity, the input duration, the encoder, the encoder settings, among other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the 2 following URL, you should be able to do what you want:

I suppose that you plan to use H264, and as the video is the major issue, First look at the following to choose the resolution & fps and the recommended bit-rate.

http://www.billhung.net/single_pages/video.encoding.resolution.vs.bitrate.by.experience.html#mozTocId728778

After follow the formula describe in: 
[Video bitrate and file size calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931200/video-bitrate-and-file-size-calculation)

to compute the file size based on the maximum video duration you choose.