# Video Bitrate calculation for uncompressed video

Tags: video, signal-processing, codec, yuv, bitrate

I am trying to understand the bit rate for uncompressed video.
But could not understand exactly while referring http://web.forret.com/tools/video_fps.asp?width=3840&height=2176&fps=30&space=yuv420&depth=4

For a **3840x2176**(width x stride) video with **30fps**, **YUV420** colorformat:

**Calculating one uncompressed frame:**

```
PixelPerFrame      = 3840 x 2176
                   = 8,355,840 pixel
```

I think, for yuv420 with 4bits per color, bits per pixel = 12

```
So, bits per frame = 12 * 8355840  
                   = 100,270,080 bits
                   = 95.625 Megabits
                   = 11.953125 MegaBytes
```

This value is atleast nearby with the reference link.

**When calculating uncompressed Video:**

```
30 fps bit rate    = 30 * sizeof one uncompressed frame.
                   = 30 * 100270080 Bits
                   = 3008,102,400 BitsPerSecond
                   = 2868.75 MegabitsPerSecond 
                   = 358.59375 MegaBytesPerSecond
```

But from the reference link i see its "188,01 MB    179,3 MiB"

**Can anyone help me to understand ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437978/1205871

Answer (score 3):

Short: YUV420 with 4 Bit per Color has 6 Bit per pixel.

Long: In YUV420 you have one `U` and one `V` value per 2x2 group of `Y`(which means the two chroma components are sampled at half the sample rate of luma both horizontally and vertically. See this [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#mediaviewer/File%3aYuv420.svg).

That means a 2x2 block of your picture has 4*4 Bit `Y` values + one 4 Bit `U` + 4 bit `V`.

that means: 2x2 pixel: 16 + 4 + 4 = 24 bit
and so :      1 pixel: 6 bit

Comment: oh !ok I understand. Thanks. But, not sure how that page shows me as 12 bits per pixel when selecting 'yuv420' as 'color model' and 'color depth' as '4 bits/pixel'. Could be a bug there !?

Comment: TBH I did not even look at the page, i just know for sure how YUV420p works. So i guess if you have a picture of ONE pixel you would need 12 bit since you can't downsample the U and V values.