# Calculate compression bitrate based on expected video resolution

Tags: android, video, compression, mp4

I'm attempting to compress video in an android application using the media api given in Android. I'm running into a problem. I am not sure what the optimal bit rate per resolution should be and research hasn't provided any insight here.

For example. I want to half the resolution

Given
1920x1080, 30fps, 250,000 bit rat,  with audio

Expect
960x540, 25fps, 200,000 bit rate, with audio

Is there a formula, or process to calculate the lowest bit rate I can provide based on the resolution and framerate? I'm compressing the audio by .75 percent but not sure if that has a similar process?

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

-Humble Android Engineer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437978/1205871

Answer (score 0):

There is no optimal solution, and there is no formula, because the answer would be different for every video. This is a very active area of research under the category of “per title encoding”.

The most common approaches to solving this are machine learning, or trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this will help guide others in this area but We decided to simply half the bitrate, unless the bitrate is going to be less than 1 bit / pixel. Seems to work well and produces good looking videos without any issues. Not saying that this is optimal but simply wanted to offer our solution.